# Play framework file hierarchy on Heroku

Tags: heroku, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to download a file  from my app, when I'm running on localhost  everything is fine  and in using this path in order to download the file

```
../myapp/public/files/67784.pdf
```

But on Heroku I'm getting `java.io.FileNotFoundException`.  How can I find location of the file on Heroku?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Public assets in Play are packaged in the Jar on compilation (makes it very convenient for moving everything around, and get them from a plugin or whatever). So you have to get them from you app Jar.

I think that you can use the Play's resource helper (http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2-SNAPSHOT/api/java/play/Application.html), but I haven't tried.

```
Play.Application.resource("public/filename")
```

Note that on Heroku, any file modification/addition on the server is lost whenever you redeploy, or restart or add an instance... The only files that persist are the ones in your Git repo.

Comment: Sorry for the iterative answer/